# Can not Install sdk in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I was going to install SDK 28 in android studio but I got following error

> Blockquote An error occurred during installation: C:\Users\sdk\platforms\android-28\android-stubs-src.jar (The system cannot find the path specified).
>   Failed to install Android SDK Platform 28!

I sdk location is ok. I previously installed sdk in that location. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does that directory exist? (C:\Users\sdk\platforms\android-28\android-stubs-src.jar)

Comment: No. But C:\Users\sdk exists. Here I installed sdk 23 in previous. I also set my sdk location here.

Comment: C:\Users\sdk\platforms this directory exists